# Burst capture in a webcam using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the `webcamjs` script to capture the webcam images for my application. its working good. My application needs a new feature called Burst capture like in mobiles and some cameras. I tried t loop thru' and called the webcamjs's snap repeatedly but i got the same images instead of diffrent one

My application is fully based on MVC, HTML and javascript.

The code i am trying to use it for burst capture

```
function burst_snapshot(burstcount,passedName) {
     for (var i = 0; i < burstcount; i++) {
          Webcam.burst_snap(function (dataurl) {
              var arrayindex = passedName + "_" + i;
              sleep(1000);
              burstcapturedata[arrayindex] = dataurl;
          }, i);
      }
}
```

> - burstcapturedata is an array to capture the returned burst data, that i need to show in a diffrent control(modal dialog)
> - burstcount is the count , i get it from the user

Comment: Sounds like you are using a `for` or `while` loop. Try using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. BTW, it helps to have the code you are asking about in the question.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - i added the code , can u have a look at it , the sleep(1000) method is to make the current loop to wait for 1 secs

Comment: As you said, your application is based on HTML too, then to capture image using webcam, Why not to use directly HTML5 media capture feature.. like this `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />`.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar - the problem is the html5 video control 's getusermedia is not supported in IE , one of the browser my project users definitely will use. Another thing is i dont know how to use the <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" /> . Sorry . :) :(

Comment: Arrgghh IE!! If that's the case, better you use some existing libraries simliar to WebCamJS..

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar - i am using the same one :) .but need of the burst capturing feature . single capture works fine with that api but there is no functions available to do the burst capture , i thought of loop thru' the burst count and take multiple single snaps. its not working , any ideas